# How to show clear button in Edit text while Editing in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to android I have just implemented the edit text in which there is a clear button on the right side, it is working fine but I want to show this clear button when user starts typing but i don't want to show this button when this edit text is empty. My xml for edit text is.

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_divider_top_email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view_divider_top_email"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view_divider_top_email"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_divider_top_email"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view_divider_top_email"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_delete" //this line will put the cross button on right of edit text
    />
```

How can I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `addTextChangeListener()` in `EditText`. It will be called when user will type or remove something from `EditText`.

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

write your logic inside `onTextChanged()` or `afterTextChanged()`, check length of `EditText` data, if it is more than 0 set `drawableRight`.

```
edt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```

else clear drawable

```
edt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: In this case how can we perform onClick on cleare button

Answer (score 0):

The following code will:

1. Add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`.
2. It will check the length.
3. If it is greater than 0 we add the delete icon to the right drawable.
4. If it is 0 then all icons are removed.

You may also want to experiment with **padding**, otherwise your text will overlap the icon when it is as long as the `EditText` itself.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length() > 0) {
            mEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, android.R.drawable.ic_delete, 0);
        } else {
            mEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using TextInputLayout attributes such as endIconDrawable

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_close"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nav_up"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    … />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```